# Need Explanation - Too Many DML Rows: 10001

Tags: apex, soql, scheduled-apex

I don't quite understand when does a transaction ends.  I have one class with 10 functions.  Each function does approximately 2000 rows inserts or Updates.  I have a total DML statements is about 16 SOQL statements for the whole class.  I'm very carefully and always do bulk inserts or updates.

So why do I still get "Too Many DML rows" error? Doesn't the transaction end after each insert or update?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The transaction does not end after each insert of update. The Governor Limits count for a so-called *execution context*. According to the Salesforce documentation this is:

> An execution context is the context information available during the
>   lifetime of a transaction. Transactions are requests initiated by
>   users when they update a record in the UI, use the API to upload
>   records, etc.
>
> Governor limits count for each execution contexts (e.g. are reset
>   between execution contexts).
>
> As an example, consider a user that updates an account record, and a
>   trigger is fired which invokes a method in a helper class. This method
>   will have to operate within the governor limits for this transaction,
>   which means that it cannot perform more SOQL queries than the current
>   maximum, etc. Additionally, if the user performs the same operation
>   almost at the same time (for instance by saving two different records
>   in two different browser tabs), each transaction will be considered a
>   separate execution context and will have its own governor limits (e.g.
>   governor limits are not shared across transactions).

https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewSolution?id=000187163&language=en_US

In other words: An execution context is all the resulting actions (methods calling each other, triggers etc.) of a request.